Conditionally adding a key to a MongoDB database with its value based on other entries
I have a MongoDB database where the structure of the data has changed between years. A sample of the data is below:
{ entry_id: 111, entrant_company:"Magic", year:2021, credit_name:"Bob Jones", credit_role:"Designer"}
{ entry_id: 111, entrant_company:"Magic", year:2021, credit_name:"Allan Jeggs", credit_role:"Director"}
{ entry_id: 111, entrant_company:"Magic", year:2021, credit_name:"Sarah Jones", credit_role:"Artist"}
{ entry_id: 348, year:2022, credit_name:"Glitter", credit_role:"Advertising Agency"}
{ entry_id: 348, year:2022, credit_name:"Jim Jones", credit_role:"Designer"}
{ entry_id: 348, year:2022, credit_name:"Allan Yi", credit_role:"Publisher"}
{ entry_id: 555, year:2023, credit_name:"Sparkle", credit_role:"Advertising Agency"}
{ entry_id: 555, year:2023, credit_name:"Josh James", credit_role:"Designer"}
{ entry_id: 555, year:2023, credit_name:"Ellen Dodd", credit_role:"Publisher"}
...

For years above 2021, I'm missing the entrant_company key, and this information is instead provided where credit_role is equal to "Advertising Agency".
Grouping my data by entry_id, how can I add a key called entrant_company and have it be set so that it's equal to credit_name where credit_role is "Advertising Agency" and the year is greater than 2021?
For clarity, my goal is to have the data look like this:
{ entry_id: 111, entrant_company:"Magic", year:2021, credit_name:"Bob Jones", credit_role:"Designer"}
{ entry_id: 111, entrant_company:"Magic", year:2021, credit_name:"Allan Jeggs", credit_role:"Director"}
{ entry_id: 111, entrant_company:"Magic", year:2021, credit_name:"Sarah Jones", credit_role:"Artist"}
{ entry_id: 348, entrant_company:"Glitter", year:2022, credit_name:"Glitter", credit_role:"Advertising Agency"}
{ entry_id: 348, entrant_company:"Glitter", year:2022, credit_name:"Jim Jones", credit_role:"Designer"}
{ entry_id: 348, entrant_company:"Glitter", year:2022, credit_name:"Allan Yi", credit_role:"Publisher"}
{ entry_id: 555, entrant_company:"Sparkle", year:2023, credit_name:"Sparkle", credit_role:"Advertising Agency"}
{ entry_id: 555, entrant_company:"Sparkle", year:2023, credit_name:"Josh James", credit_role:"Designer"}
{ entry_id: 555, entrant_company:"Sparkle", year:2023, credit_name:"Ellen Dodd", credit_role:"Publisher"}

I'm able to update a single entry like this, but I'd like to update the entrant_company for every given entry_id:
db.entries.updateMany(
    { year: { $gt: 2021 } },
    [{
        $set: {
            entrant_company: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $eq: ["$credit_role", "Advertising Agency"] },
                    then: "$credit_name",
                    else: "$$REMOVE"
                }
            }
        }
    }])


You need to join the entries collection for the document based on entry_id and credit_role: "Advertising Agency" via $lookup. However, with $lookup aggregation stage can't be performed in the .update() operation.
Thus, you need to change to the .aggregate() query and $merge stage to replace the document.

$match - Filter the documents.

$lookup - Join with entries collection by entry_id and credit_role: "Advertising Agency" and returns joined_entrant_company array.

$set - Set the entrant_company field with the first value of joined_entrant_company.credit_name.

$unset - Remove the joined_entrant_company field.

$merge - Merge the result to the entries collection by replacing the document by _id.


db.entries.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$year",
              2021
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $type: "$entrant_company"
              },
              "missing"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "entries",
      let: {
        entry_id: "$entry_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$entry_id",
                    "$$entry_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$credit_role",
                    "Advertising Agency"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "joined_entrant_company"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      entrant_company: {
        $first: "$joined_entrant_company.credit_name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "joined_entrant_company"
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "entries",
      on: "_id",
      whenMatched: "replace"
    }
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground

Note that: Mongo Playground link will only show the result with the documents that are affected (the result of the aggregate query before $merge). You can try it in MongoDB Compass. Please ensure that you clone the collection and test the query with the cloned collection before running the query to the real data.
